# Automatic sql calls when accessing controller functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

So I am trying to populate a drop down menu that displays a certain customers projects' based on which customer is selected in another drop down. I am doing this using javascript, calling the function "byProjectId" in the Project controller.

```
$("#customer_id").bind( "change", function(){
  $("#task_project_id").empty();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/projects/byCustomerId/' + $(this).val(),
      dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

My byCustomerId function is as follows:

```
def byCustomerId
  logger.debug "DEBUGGING HERE"
  if params[:id].present?
    @projects = Customer.find(params[:id]).projects.order(:name)
  else
    @projects = []
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

So all I am doing is retrieving a list of Projects based on the Customer ID value that is passed. However, when I actually run this, some extra database calls are made before my code in this method is actually executed. This is the output from the console running the rails server:

```
Started GET "/projects/byCustomerId/5?_=1342642985360" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-
18 15:23:05 -0500
Processing by ProjectsController#byCustomerId as JS
Parameters: {"_"=>"1342642985360", "id"=>"5"}
←[1m←[36mMember Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE
"members"."id" = 7 LIMIT 1←[0m
←[1m←[35mProject Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "
projects"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
Completed   in 69ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project with ID=5):
```

This shows that it is trying ask for all PROJECTS that have ID of 5, even though 5 is the Customer ID it should be asking for. When I use a different CustomerID that also happens to be a valid ProjectID, it runs the proper calls right after this, but without the RecordNotFound exception happening:

```
DEBUGGING HERE
←[1m←[36mCustomer Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
WHERE "customers"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
←[1m←[35mProject Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE (
"projects".customer_id = 1) ORDER BY name
```

The "DEBUGGING HERE" is the only way I realized these calls were being made before my code in the byCustomerId function. If the Customer ID I pass is valid as a Project ID as well, it returns the correct data and populates correctly, simply doing nothing with the data from the incorrect sql call, but when the Customer ID doesn't match up with a Project ID, these extra calls to the Database get exceptions and nothing is populated, even if the later queries would still be fine. I cannot figure out where these extra calls to the Database are coming from? Am I somehow calling them just by sending any data to the Project controller or something?

Comment: Sounds like a before filter somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, there is a "before_filter :authenticate_member!" which explains the "SELECT "members".*....." initially, but that isn't causing any issues. I will look into this more and see if that is affecting the projects call that is messing it up- authenticating if the current user has access to the project perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: What is your model association set as?

Comment: Also, have you tried instead of going across your associations do Project.where(customer_id: 5)?

Comment: Ok, it was a before filter of a kind. It was being called when this line "load_and_authorize_resource" was included, which is part of this gem the project is using to help with authorization: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan. I'm still trying to figure out how to fix it, but am on the right path now I believe.

Comment: Ah, all I had to do was add 
    skip_load_resource :only => :byCustomerId
Which still authorizes the user, but doesn't load the Project. Found here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions